# How to trouble shoot containers on ECS Fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I created a task which uses a docker image from ECR repository and a service in ECS. The running environment is `Fargate` so there is no ec2 instance running. After I configure all the resources, the status of the service is `ACTIVATE`, but the status of the task is `STOPPED` with the reason

```
Status reason   CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: Get https://773592622512.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

The docker image I put on the task definition is `773592622512.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/flask:latest`.

I see empty log stream when I click `View logs in CloudWatch`. I wonder how I can debug this issue? Do I have to deploy the container to ec2 in order to see more detailed error messages?

I have added this policy to the task role: `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess`. Why can't it pull

Answer (score 1):

After some debug I found the issue is solved by adding a source `0.0.0.0/0` pointing to a internet gateway in subnet associated with the VPC used by the task. Then enable `Assign public IP address` when define the task. AWS doesn't give me much useful log for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Try having your Auto-assign Public IP enabled when launching a Fargate task. When you run a task on Fargate via the AWS Console, you should see the setting for this under the `VPC and security groups` header.